# ScrollDown page to the next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

When the user *scrolldown* with the *mousewheel*, I'd like the page go down untill exactly the begining of the next element. Like :

```
<section class="One">
   ...
</section>

<section class="Two">
   ...
</section>

<section class="Three">
   ...
</section>
```

When you enter the website, you'll be at the start page, when you scrolldown 1x, I'd like the page scroll untill the begining of section 2 and so on...

Imagine the sections like, *home / about / contact*

I tried this, but in this example, I have to write the exactly name of the elements and I would have to write one of this for each section... Is there a different way to do so ?

```
   window.onload=function myScroll() {
     x = document.getElementById("chat");
     h = x.clientHeight;
     x.scrollTop = h;
    }

<div id="chat" style="width: 100%; height: 70px; overflow: scroll;
        border: 1px solid grey">
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be quite complicated due to the fact that this involves scrolling, catching the mouse wheel events, delay in animations, cross browser usage, swipe and touch events. Fortunately, there are plugins available to make your life easier. One of the most popular ones is **[Full Page](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)**.

**Some of the features include:**

- Usage over old browsers with no CSS3 support.
- Add a live menu.
- Slide throw the page using the keyboard arrows.
- Add horizontal sliders.
- Mobile and Tablet detection enabling the scrolling on them.

**Usage:**

Each section will be defined with a `div` containing the `section` class.

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="slide"> Slide 1 </div>
    <div class="slide"> Slide 2 </div>
    <div class="slide"> Slide 3 </div>
    <div class="slide"> Slide 4 </div>
</div>
```

All you need to do is call the plugin inside a `$(document).ready` function:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();
});
```

**[Demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)**